# I can't connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, kohana

I use Kohana 3.2, and when I insert in the index.php controller `$query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER By id DESC');`, I see the error ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Database' not found. What do I do?

Comment: This is code error and doesn't have to do anything with connection to database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a database error. The database class cannot be found and I'm almost sure it's because of following reasons:

You probably haven't installed and configured the database module properly. Make sure that the database module is in the module path you specified in the index file:

```
$modules = '../your/path/to/modules';
```

Furthermore, enable the module in your bootstrap (application/bootstrap.php):

```
Kohana::modules(array(
  // Rest of modules
  'database' => MODPATH.'database',
));
```

More info about modules can be found here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/modules

Comment: How to get data from database with kohana?

Comment: That's an entirely different question. Do you still get the error?

Comment: No, I not see anything, but I in database posted two posts.

Comment: If you don't see an error anymore, then something else is going on. I suggest you make a new question, because I don't know what's wrong unless I see your code.